# ¿Cómo variar los decimales usando Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Ejecuto mi código con enteros y va bien, ejemplo:

```
let modifier = Math.floor(Math.random()*30 + 1);
```

Pero ahora lo que quería era obtener variaciones con decimales ejemplo:

> ```
> 0.00000070 0.00000075 asi hasta 0.00000090
> ```

El codigo que intente pero no me da la variacion es este:

```
number = 0.00000070 + Math.floor(Math.random()*0.00000020 + 0.00000001)
```

¿Cómo podría hacer para que funcione?

Answer (score 3):

Puedes probar con esto amigo, espero haya sido de ayuda!

```
number = 0.00000070 + Math.floor(Math.random()*0.00000020 + 0.00000001)
number.toFixed(8)
```

Puedes utilizar el `.toFixed` para convertir el resultado: *"7e7"* en *"0.00000007"*.

El número **8** es la longitud de números a la derecha.

Answer (score 1):

Aportando un valor máximo y mínimo para la variación puedes conseguir que varíen los decimales en ese rango. Además debes eliminar `Math.floor` ya que redondeo impide ver el resultado, de hecho bastaría con eliminarlo para que funcione tu código.

```js
let modifier = Math.floor(Math.random()*30 + 1);
console.log(modifier);
var min = 0.00000001;
var max = 0.00000020
number = 0.00000070 + (Math.random()*(max - min) + min);
console.log(number.toFixed(8));
//eliminando floor
number2 = 0.00000070 + (Math.random()*0.00000020 + 0.00000001);
console.log(number2.toFixed(8));
```

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro si entendí bien, pero creo que esto puede ayudar. Hace algún tiempo necesite algo parecido. Esta función recibe la cantidad de posiciones que necesitas de un numero random, y devuelve un numero decimal entre cero y 10^posiciones - 1. La contra es que la distribución de probabilidad supongo que no es gaussiana.

```js
Math.hRandom = function(posiciones) {

  var numero = "";
  const coma = Math.floor(Math.random() * posiciones) + 1;

  for (let i = 0; i < posiciones; i++) {
    if (i == coma) numero += ".";
    numero += Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
  }

  return numero;

}

//Desde 000000000.1 hasta 9999999999
console.log(Math.hRandom(10));
```